# Completion in vim with ctags

Tags: php, zend-framework, vim, ctags

So I followed with [this](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/134-exuberant-ctags-with-PHP-in-Vim.html) instruction and everything is fine but it would be nice if I have auto complete (like omni completion, method name, class name etc.) with this generated tag. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The omnicompletion "contextual menu" is obtained by hitting `<C-x><C-o>`.

Comment: Yeaa I know, omnicompletion is working but how enable completion zend class name or method name in vim (LIKE in omnicompletion) with generated tag file with ctags?

Comment: Did you try [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171)? I think it will handle you tags file better than the default omnicomplete function.